# Writing to my log not working

Tags: c#, logging

I've written the next class that should write to my txt file, but it isn't working.

```
public class Logger
{
    public StreamWriter file { get; set; }
    public void OpenLog() {
        file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/log"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".txt", true);
        file.Flush();
    }

    public void WriteLog(string message) {
        file.Write(message + "\n");
    }

    public void CloseLog() {
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

Below is how I call the class and methods, and it does create the logfile, but it doesn't write to the file.

```
Logger l = new Logger();
l.OpenLog();
l.WriteLog("hello");
l.CloseLog();
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: what you mean by *not working*?

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong because that code works OK. Are you sure you're looking at the right file? - (Ran in LinqPad - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUr75.png)

Comment: @Rahul Well it's not writing in the file, but it do create the file.

Comment: If you need to use logging, but don't actually need to code it yourself then better use [NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/). It takes a day to figure it out (also to figure Nuget out), but it is extremely useful.

Comment: As an aside, you should always use `Path.Combine` rather than manually sticking strings together.

Comment: .. `Environment.CurrentDirectory` isn't always what you think it will be..

Comment: Logger should probably be an IDisposable to allow you to dispose the StreamWriter.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm not sure what that is, any change you could throw an example with my code at me?, but thanks

Comment: Few questions to get a bit of an idea what is going wrong. 1. have you tried doing `file.Flush();` after the `file.write`? 2. If you do `l.OpenLog();`  immediately after the close do you get an error? 3. have you tried debugging and seen the file actually getting closed?

Comment: i think the log is not getting flushed to the file .Try adding `File.Flush` in the 'write()' method .